# Exporting from three.js scene to SVG or other vector format

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js, webgl

Is is possible to export an SVG- or other vector-formatted image from a scene rendered with three.js's `WebGLRenderer`? Is it possible with a scene derived from `CanvasRenderer`?

Failing that, how does one actually set up `SVGRenderer` with three.js? Instantiating a new `THREE.SVGRenderer()` in v69 appears to return an error in the console, for instance, indicating that the constructor is not available. The documentation for three.js does not appear to include details about `SVGRenderer`. Once set up, is it possible to use textures and particles with `SVGRenderer`, as is done in `WebGLRenderer`?

Comment: Take a look at the example http://threejs.org/examples/#svg_sandbox

Answer (score 5):

I had also task to export svg from three.js and here's working solution that works. it uses SVGRenderer:

```js
var controls;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
  camera.position.x = 2;
  camera.position.y = 1;
  camera.position.z = 3;
  camera.zoom = 3.6;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.4, 0.2, 0.2);
  material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight - 70);

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.update();

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function btnSVGExportClick() {
  var rendererSVG = new THREE.SVGRenderer();
  
  rendererSVG.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  rendererSVG.render(scene, camera);
  ExportToSVG(rendererSVG, "test.svg");
}

function ExportToSVG(rendererSVG, filename) {
  var XMLS = new XMLSerializer();
  var svgfile = XMLS.serializeToString(rendererSVG.domElement);
  var svgData = svgfile;
  var preface = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>\r\n';
  var svgBlob = new Blob([preface, svgData], {
    type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"
  });
  var svgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  
  downloadLink.href = svgUrl;
  downloadLink.download = filename;
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  downloadLink.click();
  document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/SVGRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>

<input id="btnSVGExport" type="button" value="Get as SVG" onclick="btnSVGExportClick()" style="margin-bottom:3px">
```

Just save this code as some.html file and use Get as SVG button to save to svg file. jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/9y0b3wet/

Comment: Is there any way for it to only export items that are visible in the current orientation? It seems to export everything in the scene, even if it's hidden by other objects resulting in a huge SVG?

Comment: sorry I can't help you. I don't have much experience with threejs. just was working with it for few months.